# Syntax Highlighting for MySQL Shells?

Tags: shell, mysql, syntax-highlighting

Are there any MySQL shells that support syntax highlighting?  I know in my.cnf, you can set the shell string with, for example:

```
[mysql]
prompt=(\\u@\\h) [\\d]>\\_
```

But is there any more customization possible?  I'd love to have some colors or syntax highlighting.  And if it's not possible with the default MySQL shell, are there any alternate shells for MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question, try [vim](http://www.vim.org) with [dbext](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [AltSQL](http://ewaters.github.com/altsql-shell/) ([Github](https://github.com/ewaters/altsql-shell)).

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL workbench](http://www.mysql.de/products/workbench/) is very comfortable. But i wouldn't call it shell in a common way.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a shell either :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question but recently, [MyCLI](https://www.mycli.net/) has been pretty user-friendly and complete.